# What if an object's fields is an object...is there a way to get the latter object's fields?

Tags: java, oop, reflection

I'm writing a program wherein I need to check an object's field values. For example, I have a class called Book which has String bookName, String publisher, and Author author. In Author, it has fields such as String firstName, String lastName, String dateOfBirth. I want to get the author's last name and change it to a new last name by looking through the fields of the Book. Also, I have to implement my method in a way wherein any kind of object can be used so method can also be used when changing first name of just the author.

I have used getDeclaredFields() to loop through the fields of my Book object, and am trying to find if one of the fields is its own object.

I have used "instanceof" Author but I need to find a way that doesn't need my hardcoding of the class name "Author"

```java
public ArrayList<String> makeChanges(Object book){
ArrayList<String> changeList= new ArrayList<String>;
try{
Field[] bookFields = book.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

String changes = "";

for (Field field: bookFields){
    field.setAccessible(true);
    if (field.getName().equals("firstName")){
        if (!(field.get(book).equals("Twilight"))){
            changes = field.getName() + changed to "Twilight";
            changeList.add(changes);
        }
    if (field.get(book) instanceof Author){
        List<String> authorChanges = makeChanges(field.get(book));
        changes = Arrays.toString(authorChanges.toArray()).replace("[","").replace("]","");
        changeList.add(changes);
    }
}

catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.toString());
}

return changeList;
}
```

Actual result: [bookName changed to "Twilight", author changed to "demo.Address@16f65612"]

Expected result should be: [bookName changed to "Twilight", firstName changed to "Eli"]

Comment: If you need to change the value of a field, call the appropriate setter method on the object, e.g. call the `setFirstName(String firstName)` method on the `Author` object. No need to use reflection. It's actually discouraged to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the object is primitive data type and wrapper classes. You can check the object using recursive function. Please find below the implementation classes that might suit your needs.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookAuthor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.bookName = "Twiligh";
        book.publisher = "Oreilly";
        book.author = new Author();
        book.author.firstName = "";
        book.author.lastName = "Elo";
        ArrayList<String> changeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(makeChanges(book,changeList));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> makeChanges(Object book,ArrayList<String> changeList) {

        try {
            Field[] bookFields = book.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            Object object;

            for (Field field : bookFields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                object = field.get(book);
                if(object!=null && isWrapperAndPrimitiveType(object.getClass())) {      
                    if(field.getName().equals("bookName")) {
                        if(!object.equals("Twilight")) {
                            field.set(book, "Twilight");
                            changeList.add(field.getName()+" changed to Twilight");
                        }
                    }
                    if(field.getName().equals("lastName")) {
                        if(!object.equals("Eli")) {
                            field.set(book, "Eli");
                            changeList.add(field.getName()+" changed to Eli");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(object!=null && !isWrapperAndPrimitiveType(object.getClass())) {                 
                    makeChanges(object,changeList);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return changeList;
    }


    public static boolean isWrapperAndPrimitiveType(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(Boolean.class) || 
            clazz.equals(Integer.class) ||
            clazz.equals(Character.class) ||
            clazz.equals(Byte.class) ||
            clazz.equals(Short.class) ||
            clazz.equals(Double.class) ||
            clazz.equals(Long.class) ||
            clazz.equals(Float.class)||
            clazz.equals(String.class) ||
            clazz.equals(boolean.class) || 
            clazz.equals(int.class) ||
            clazz.equals(char.class) ||
            clazz.equals(byte.class) ||
            clazz.equals(short.class) ||
            clazz.equals(double.class) ||
            clazz.equals(long.class) ||
            clazz.equals(float.class) ;
    }
}
```

Book class

```
public class Book {
    String bookName;
    String publisher;
    Author author;
}
```

Author class

```
public class Author {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String dateOfBirth;
}
```